# Extract one of many possible input

Tags: c#, regex

My regexp input looks like that:

```
xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzDays</td> <td>15/td>xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
xyzxyzxyzDays</td> <td>25/td>xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
xyzxyzxyz
xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzDays</td> <td>8/td>xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
```

xyzxyzxyz - thats the html code.

I want to extract a number which is behind first `Days` appear. So it would be `15`. Im scraping that from website, so that number is changing.

I managed that code:

```
    MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(sourceCode, @"Days</td> <td>(\d+)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    List<string> adresy = new List<string>();

    foreach (Match m in m1)
    {
        string adres = m.Groups[1].Value;
        adresy.Add(adres);
        label1.Text = adres;
    }
```

But that gives me `8` insted of `15`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I don't see the phrase "Unique Visitors" anywhere in your input, so you aren't showing us everything.  Please show us your *entire* input, or at least all of the pertinent input, and explain more precisely what you're trying to match with your desired pattern.

Comment: Sorry i have made mistake.

Comment: Try Regex.Match instead of Regex.Matches.

Comment: Yes, you need the first match. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gX3yD9/1). Take out `label1.Text = adres;` from the `foreach`, put it after it, and use `label1.Text = adresy[0];`. And replace the first two lines inside foreach with `adresy.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that you update your label text upon each `foreach` iteration. You need to update it only after the addresses are collected. Replace your whole `foreach` with

```
adresy = m1.Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
label1.Text = adresy.Count > 0 ? adresy[0] : string.Empty;
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/T1Zx16):

```
var sourceCode = "xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\nxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzDays</td> <td>15/td>xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\nxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\nxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\nxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\nxyzxyzxyzDays</td> <td>25/td>xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\nxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\nxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\nxyzxyzxyz\nxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\nxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzDays</td> <td>8/td>xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\nxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\nxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\nxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz"; 
var adresy = Regex.Matches(sourceCode, @"Days</td> <td>(\d+)")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
            .ToList();
var labelText = adresy.Count > 0 ? adresy[0] : string.Empty;
Console.WriteLine(labelText);
```